# Can't set headers after they ar sent NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with my route :

```js
let passport = require('passport');
let appkey = require('../keyapp').init;

/**
 * @param  {Express} app
 */
function initApp(app) {
    app.get('/app', renderApp);

}
/**
 * @param  {request} req
 * @param  {response} res
 * @param {string} messageReq
 */
function renderApp(req, res, messageReq) {
    let message = '';
    let connected = false;

    if (messageReq) {
        message = messageReq;
    }
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        connected = true;
    }
    res.render('application/index', {
        connected: connected,
        message: message,
    });
}

module.exports = initApp;
```

So i get : `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I really don't know why, and i need to put more words to be able to post, so it is ok i think

Comment: messageReq, dunno what you think it is, but that's a function. If you want the params they are in the req object. req.query, or req.params depending how you pass them

Answer (score 0):

> `Can't set headers after they are sent error

` you will get when you pass statements after sending a response.

For example:

```
res.send("response");
console.log("some message");
res.send("some other response");
```

Above statement Will  result in the error you are seeing, because once the response has been sent, the following `res.send` will not be executed.

If you want do anything, you should do it before sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @ybrodsky (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655756/ybrodsky), the third parameters wasn't used correctly, i wanted to pass some messages in the futur